# Emacs parenthesis match colors styling

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I'm using prelude emacs with solarized theme and parenthesis highlights are hardly visible and looking very ugly. I've tried disabling `show-smartparen-mode` also `show-paren-mode` but nothing seems to disable it. I'm not sure, which mode is making highlight parenthesis. Please check the image below:

[image]

I would like to change background color of parenthesis to something else so it is more visible. I would appreciate if anyone could provide any help/comments in this regards. Thanks!

### EDIT

Problem: The matching parenthesis highlight, if you look at image above, my cursor is immediate right of the `)` therefore `(` and `)`  are highlighted in bluish shade which is not visible.

What I want: I would somehow like to change background color of this highlight.

Comment: 1. It's not clear what you want. It's not even clear what you do *not* want -- what you don't like about the behavior you see now.  You do not even describe that behavior. Don't make us guess from a screenshot what *you* find objectionable and what *you* would prefer.

2. If you want to find out what code highlights a given character, it can sometimes help to find out what the highlighting face is. To do that, put the cursor on the highlighted char and hit `C-u C-x =`. With luck, the name of the face mentioned in the help will start with a prefix that gives you a hint what the library is.

Comment: @Drew I'm sorry for not being clear. I've editted the document, I hope it is more clearer now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing `C-u C-x =` with the cursor on the highlighted parenthesis, you will know what the highlighting face is. If you just want to change its background color, then do `M-x customize-face` *`FACE`*, where *`FACE`* is the face name.